# Craft 3 query children of sub categories

Tags: craft3, categories

Just wondering how to only query the children on subcategories. For example...

```
Food
├── Fruit
│   ├── Apples
│   ├── Bananas
│   └── Oranges
└── Vegetables
    ├── Brussels sprouts
    ├── Carrots
    └── Celery
```

I only want to query the children directly of fruit without having to get all of the food then have to loop around. As this isn't the best practice.

I thought it would be something like ...

```
{% set categories = craft.categories()
.group('food')
.ancestorOf('fruit')
.all() %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ancestor of expects and element or the ID of an element, not a string. You should pass the proper parameter

Answer (score 3):

Building on [Robin's comment](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28063/craft-3-query-children-of-sub-categories#comment36550_28063), the [ancestorOf](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/category-queries.html#parameters) parameter expects either an element ID or the actual element as a parameter.

For example, if you know the ID of the `fruit` category is `3`, you'd use `.anscestorOf(3)`, or if you already had the fruit category element, you'd do like so:

```
{% set fruitCategory = craft.categories.id(3).one() %}

{% set categories = craft.categories()
    .group('food')
    .ancestorOf(fruitCategory)
    .all() %}
```

Comment: Thank for getting back to me.

I tried this and its still not working. So I dumped out "fruitCategory" and i was getting this returned...

/home/vagrant/code/craft/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php:50:null

any ideas?

As a result it just returns everything

Answer (score 1):

`.ancestorOf(fruitCategory)` would be going up the structure. The ancestor of Fruit in this example is Food. If you want the children of Fruit you'd use `.decendantOf(fruitCategory)`

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#descendantof